# restrict access to specific urls on a specific period of time

Tags: functions, customization, shortcode, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I have a countdown timer plugin which is set do redirect the user to a specific permalink after the time is elapsed.

I've added a countdown timer here : mywebsite.com/mypost  which is set to 3 days and after the time is over I will be redirected to mywebsite.coom/mypost/countdownover.

What  I need is to block access to those specific permalinks till the countdown is over.

The permalink for the post is built like this:

```
function wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints(){
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'countdownover', EP_PERMALINK );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'wpa121567_rewrite_endpoints' );
```

The countdown plugin which I'm using has some callbacks available through Javascript but I don't want this because is not secure in this way.

A nice way of doing this is to add that endpoint only if the countdown time is over but this is impossible in php.

I was thinking also to remove the shortcode after the countdown is over and then check if shortcode exists and if not exists then apply the endpoint but this is not possible also.

Any idea on how can I restrict access to that url till the countdown is over?

L.E: 
I've resolved this by adding a plugin which allow me to hide the content based on a period of time so this is better for me because I have more flexibility and it have also shortcode support.

Comment: How is the expiration date stored? You need to check that time against the current time when a request is processed on your server.

Comment: I've resolved this by adding a plugin which allow me to hide the content based on a period of time so this is better for me because I have more flexibility and it have also shortcode support.